# How to replace text in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, base64

I have email templates in `mail_template` table.
There are image (base64 encoded) in template.
I need change this image another. How to replace text in mysql?

I saw some answers, about `replace()` function, but this function is working only string. I tried `replace()` function, but doesn't work. How can I resolve it?

Comment: You probably need a lot more than `REPLACE()` to do this, e.g. regular expressions.  I would lean towards doing to replacement in the app layer, and then update MySQL afterwards.

Comment: Explain to database structure and Replace query..

Comment: I am using InnoDB table.query like that:  `UPDATE mail_template
SET message_body = REPLACE(message_body, 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAYAAAAeP4ixAAAAAX....', 'http://xxx.xyz/image.png') where message_body like '%data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAYAAAAeP4ixAAAAAX....%'`